# How to move a matrix from one side to another when it's somewhere in the middle

Tags: linear-algebra

If I want to move a matrix $A$ from one side of equation of another I can multiply both sides with inverse matrix from the left:

$$ABC = DEF \\
A^{-1}ABC = A^{-1}DEF$$

I can also do the same thing from the right side:

$$BCA = DEF \\
BCAA^{-1} = DEFA^{-1}$$

But how do we move matrix A if it's somewhere in between ex:

$$BAC = DEF$$

Also when dealing with vectors, as in example below where matrices on the left and right side are multiplied with vectors, do the same rules apply when moving the matrices from one side to another?

$$BCAv_1 = DEFv_2 \\
BCAA^{-1}v_1 = DEFA^{-1}v_2$$

Comment: In general, you cannot "move a matrix from the middle to the sides". As for vectors, if $M = N$ then $Mv = Nv,$ so if $BCA = DEF$ then $BCAv = DEFv,$ and similarly since $BC = DEFA^{-1},$ then $BCv = DEFA^{-1}v.$

Comment: You can peel the matrices by multiplying with inverses from the left or from the right. For example in $BAC = DEF$ you can multiply on the left by $A^{-1}B^{-1}$ to move $A$.

Comment: In general, you will have to "peel off" the entries from one side or the other:
$$BAC=DEF$$ $$AC = B^{-1}DEF$$ $$C = A^{-1}B^{-1}DEF$$ If you want, you can then push them back after moving $A$: $$BC = BA^{-1}B^{-1}DEF$$

Comment: @WilliamM. Yes sorry I made a mistake I meant something like this $$BCAv_1 = DEFv_2 \\
BCAA^{-1}v_1 = DEFA^{-1}v_2$$

Comment: @MPW and others, very helpful, thank you very much!